# What is the conversion of a blast radius measured in milli creepers to an actual measurement?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

Can someone explain the blast radius (from the center outward) of 500 milli creepers?  (I assume that 1 creeper = 1000 milli creepers)

I'm asking this because, on the FTB wiki, under power armor, it says the plasma cannon has a blast radius of 500 milli creepers.  I'm trying to figure out what that means in an actual measurement.

Answer (score 1):

Millicreepers is a way of measuring blast radiuses (radii?). A creeper's blast radius is an easy to compare to as it is a common vanilla feature. As you said and the [FTBWiki](http://ftbwiki.org/Plasma_Cannon) states, the blast radius of the plasma cannon is 500 millicreepers (.5 creepers) or **1/2 the radius of a creepers explosion**.

Reference this picture:
[image]

The explosion on the right is that of a regular creeper (the one on the left is a charged creeper). Now halve that and you have the explosion size for the plasma cannon. Take note that with harder blocks the explosion radius will be smaller. If you are curious you can find the list of block blast resistances here: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Explosion#Blast_resistance

*Extra Info:* On the [Explosion](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Explosion) page of the Minecraft wiki, the power levels of explosions are also listed. Creepers are listed as having a power level of 3. So the plasma cannon would rate a level of 1.5 which is slightly higher than that of a ghast fireball or wither heads.

Comment: It should be the explosion on the LEFT that is that of a regular creeper, as it's bigger, and the right one is 500mc

Comment: @private_meta The one on the RIGHT is a regular creeper explosion because this is taken from the minecraft wiki since I have no desire to turn on my computer at 2 AM to take a screenshot of an explosion... The one on the left is a charged creeper.

Comment: Oh, didn't see the "charged creeper" in the parenthesis, sorry, my fault. I just went for the bigger explosion.

Comment: @private_meta I actually added that in after you said that, I guess I just really didn't expect people to question what the other explosion was, haha

Answer (score 0):

Milli=1000th, 1000mc%2=500mc, so 500 millicreepers=1/2 a creeper, so outward
Creeper ex. Radius halved = 500 millicreepers!

Answer (score 0):

**Approximately four meters wide**

Based on Johnny's answer, we can see that a Creeper explodes outward, in ideal situations, roughly 3 blocks from the position in which it explodes (give or take about half a block).  If we include the original block the Creeper is in, that's a 4-block 'radius' in the four cardinal directions.  Cutting that in half would yeild a 2-block radius.  Though I have no image to reference for the Plasma Cannon, your rough estimate for the blast radius is 2 Blocks, or roughly all blocks surrounding the point of impact.  The force upward will likely be greater than the force downward, since each block of ground has to be penetrated.

Now, esince the user ased for *actual* measurements...a Minecraft block is 1 meter tall, wide and deep.  So if we were to smooth out the Minecraft world, what we'd end up with is a blast radius of approximately 2 meters, plus or minus about half a meter, which means the blast is somewhere between 3 and 5 meters wide - approximately 4 meters wide.

Answer (score -1):

The minecraft wiki explains why "blast radius" is not easily defined and also has a table of relative blast strengths.  The ftb creeper as far as I know is the same as vanilla and we can assume 500 millicreepers is half the strength of a creeper. I can't post a link to the wiki but if you google “minecraft explosions" you will find It.